# Можно ли сделать файл бд формата mdf общим для двух проектов

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня имеется два проекта: консольное приложение, приложение asp.net mvc. Можно ли сделать так что бы один файл бд использовался для двух проектов (через entity framework)? Если да, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: Зачем спрашивать, просто попробуйте

Comment: А как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Bald нет, не к вам

Comment: Ну как, если у вас есть программа, что подключается к бд - запустите ее 2 раза и поглядите результат.

Comment: Подключение идет именно к файлу .mdf или к SQL-серверу?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов к файлу

Comment: Покажите как именно - что прописано в connection Sting? . Скорее всего у вас используется localdb с attachdbfilename.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по всему, у вас используется SQL Server LocalDB (entity framework пытается подключиться именно к нему, если в строке подключения указан только файл). А этот вариант, насколько мне известно, могу ошибаться, одновременные подключения не поддерживает.

Вам нужен полноценный сервер, хотя бы вариант Express. К mdf-файлу подключается сервер, а уже к серверу несколько клиентов.

Comment: Запустил 2 Linqpad - подключился в обоих к LocalDB - что я делаю не так? Оно вроде удаленные подключения не поддерживает, а локальных то может быть и 2

Comment: @tym32167 Там еще есть разница, использовать InitialCatalog (предварительно выполнив Create Database) или AttachDbFilename. Второй способ не позволяет одновременные подключения ни в LocalDB,  ни в полноценном SQL Server. Но так или иначе, и LocalDB, и AttachDbFilename для asp.net mvc не особо подходят.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну, localdb вообще не для прода по идее. Но у автора нет никаких деталей в вопросе :) мож ему для тестов надо, кто ж его знает, что автор хочет и как подключаться